# How to completely hide the ExtJS Source Code in browsers inspect element?

Tags: extjs

I have an EXTJS app and when I look at the source by using browser's inspect element I can see my entire app's source code (except for the server-side code ofcourse.).

I have seen some extjs apps that when inspecting theie source code, all I can see is the app.html page and non of their .js files is discover able by the browser.

I was wondering how I should configure my EXTJS app to make them not viewable inside the browsers "Sources" tab (ie.  Chrome's Inspect Element > Sources).

Any help is much appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is to obfuscate your code, as there is no way to stop someone looking at it once its got to the browser.

Even if the browser could hide it somehow, there is nothing stopping a user sniffing the packets on the network etc.

Comment: Thanks, I also read many threads where its indicated that once the code is on the client side, it's not possible to not let the user see the source.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to configure the EXTJS to load the js sources in a way that will not show anything of them except for the mainViewport.js or the app.js / app.html ?

Comment: No, not possible. To run the code, it has to be sent to the client. The best you can do is obfuscate it.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. What's the best way to obfuscate it?

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: Apache and Java for server-side